# java.lang.ClassCastException.How to remove?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

`["android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText"]`
getting this error (`runtimeException`), apping is crashing every time i open it . Its a signup activity in android studio.
Could anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: share xml and code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You are trying to cast an `AppCompatTextView` to `EditText` that means When you find XML view with `findViewById()` you add `AppCompatTextView` id to `EditText` view. So just change the Id or view can solve your problem.

Comment: Welcome. If my answer helps you to solve your problem, You should accept my answer by clicking the tick mark or upvote this answer.